# By using union operator I want to get single record with same id but different name

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i created one table with(id,name) like (1,justin)...
second table like(1,jstin).
By using union operator i want to display what was the correct name ?(here correct name was justin) how it is possible?

Comment: How do you decide what name is the correct one?

Comment: yeah, sorry ..by seeing this question i can easily decided..but 100 records i cant decide..how to decide database ?

Comment: I am with @ZoharPeled on this. There is no way that an SQL query can tell you which name is correct, unless you provide some logic or rules for what denotes correctness. If you (as the intelligent end user) know that "Justin" is more correct than "Jstin", that is great, but you need to provide a rule along the lines of: "If the names have different lengths, then the longer name is always correct"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the below

```
 create table tab2
 (
  col1 integer,
  col2 varchar(100)
 );

 insert into tab1 values (1,'Justin');

  create table tab2
  (
   col1 integer,
   col2 varchar(100)
  );

  insert into tab2 values (1,'Jstin');
```

Basically you want to print the right name from tab1.
We can do this in many ways .we don't actually want a union operator here.But if you are specifically looking for union to do this,please try the below

```
 select distinct id,correct_name  from 
 (
    select distinct col1 as id,col2 as correct_name,null as worng_name from 
    tab1 
    union 
    select distinct col1 as id,null as correct_name,col2 as wrong_name  from 
    tab2
 )a
    where correct_name is not null;
```

Comment: if this is not what you are expecting post the details of what the table has and what is the expected result

Comment: @ aparna..actually we dont know which table has correct name....how will you give col2 as correct_name,null as worng_name from 
    tab1  .........................

Comment: Your solution is based on the assumption (not confirmed by OP) that the right values are the ones in tab1. If this was the case the best thing to do is just to select from tab1 (you don't need union)

Comment: my intension is how database knows the correct name ? in 1000 records 500 names in tab1 is correct..remaining records tab2 is correct

Comment: @Beiber,my assumption was that the tab2 has the wrong names.It would be better to rephrase your question to address this.By the way the question now is if you are not sure which is the right name then both the names 'Justin' and 'jstin' is possible .So you should have a match table or soemthing which has the correct names mapped right ?

Comment: @mauro..using union how  will i  get? i mean how to do  database check the spells

Comment: A spell check between names is impossible since both the names are possible right ?

Comment: @ aparna..yes ..if we dnt  sure which is the right name.then how it is?

Comment: First of all we need to understand the source of both the tables where we have the right/wrong name and decide on which tables name we should pick .It is ideal to pick the name from the right table which is the actual source of data